# How to save the tree view node locally in javascript

Tags: javascript

In the below code I have two buttons, first child and the last child.

Using `getdata()` I have added the tree view node and child node named as building and floor.
Now under the floors, I'm able to add the child first and last but, after reloading the page it's not there.

After reloading the page, i want the nodes to displayed like that only.

I want to save the tree view nodes locally while loading the page

Can any one please help me?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- You need to include these. -->
<link href="https://cdn.grapecity.com/wijmo/5.latest/styles/wijmo.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.grapecity.com/wijmo/5.latest/controls/wijmo.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.grapecity.com/wijmo/5.latest/controls/wijmo.nav.min.js"></script>


<div class="col-xs-5">
      <div id="theTree">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
      <p>
        Building:
        <input class="form-control" id="theInput" value="My New Node">
      </p>
      <p>
        Floors:
        <button id="btnFirst" class="btn btn-default">First Child</button>
        <button id="btnLast" class="btn btn-default">Last Child</button>
      </p>
      <p>
        <button id="btnNoSel" class="btn btn-default">Remove Selection</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">

onload = function() {

  // create the tree
  var theTree = new wijmo.nav.TreeView('#theTree', {
    itemsSource: getData(),
    displayMemberPath: 'header',
    childItemsPath: 'items'
  });
  theTree.selectedItem = theTree.itemsSource[0];

  // handle buttons
 document.getElementById('btnFirst').addEventListener('click', function () {
   var newItem = { header: document.getElementById('theInput').value },
      node = theTree.selectedNode;
  if (node) {
      theTree.selectedNode = node.addChildNode(0, newItem);
  } else {
    theTree.selectedNode = theTree.addChildNode(0, newItem);
  }
 });
 document.getElementById('btnLast').addEventListener('click', function () {
   var newItem = { header: document.getElementById('theInput').value },
      node = theTree.selectedNode;
  if (node) {
     var index = node.nodes ? node.nodes.length : 0;
     theTree.selectedNode = node.addChildNode(index, newItem);
  } else {
     var index = theTree.nodes ? theTree.nodes.length : 0;
     theTree.selectedNode = theTree.addChildNode(index, newItem);
  }
 });
  document.getElementById('btnNoSel').addEventListener('click', function () {
   theTree.selectedNode = null;
 });

  // create some data
  function getData() {
    return [
     { header: 'Building', items: [
       { header: 'Floors' },
        ]
     },  
  ];
  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: JS plugin / library required for 'wijmo' doesn't seems in the code.

Comment: @NitinDhomse see my edited post

Comment: You need to save or persist the changes you made for tree view, store it in database or in the cookie, retrieve it after page load and re-generate structure by passing these saved data.

Comment: @NitinDhomse can you please give some example or can you please edit my code

Comment: @NitinDhomse please help me

Comment: For how long and under what conditions do you want to retain the data? page reload, browser closed, tab closed are some of the scenarios.

Comment: once i was added node to parent then it like constant.